# How to make compile task depend on some other task in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

For example, I need to do some pre-processing of source files before compiling. How do I ensure that sbt always runs this task before `compile` if `compile` was requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I do to make sure my tests are run before I publish locally:

```
publishLocal <<= publishLocal dependsOn (test in Test)
```

For you I think you'd need something like

```
compile <<= compile dependsOn (myTask in myContext)
```

Comment: Not valid with sbt 10+ sadly... Looking for a way to do exactly this but on 11.2